# query index with asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I would like to know how can I query index from asp.net application. I have the index ready but I would like to know how I can query, should I do something different then normal query, how can I utilize better to improve the search?
Thanks, Laziale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't query the index, SQL chooses it if needed.

 

 
Test the query with SSMS and see if it is included in plan.